# I have too many watchers in Vuejs, and my code is not scalable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to make this code shorter/ scalable: (just adding a lot of the code here to demonstrate the amount I have to write per item)

```
    hoodiesml: false,
    hoodiemed: false,
    hoodielrg: false,
    hoodiexlrg: false,
    hoodiexxlrg: false,

    hoodiesmlqty: 0,
    hoodiemedqty: 0,
    hoodielrgqty: 0,
    hoodiexlrgqty: 0,
    hoodiexxlrgqty: 0,

    hoodiesmltot: 0,
    hoodiemedtot: 0,
    hoodielrgtot: 0,
    hoodiexlrgtot: 0,
    hoodiexxlrgtot: 0,

    shirtsml: false,
    shirtmed: false,
    shirtlrg: false,
    shirtxlrg: false,
    shirtxxlrg: false,

    shirtsmlqty: 0,
    shirtmedqty: 0,
    shirtlrgqty: 0,
    shirtxlrgqty: 0,
    shirtxxlrgqty: 0,

    shirtsmltot: 0,
    shirtmedtot: 0,
    shirtlrgtot: 0,
    shirtxlrgtot: 0,
    shirtxxlrgtot: 0,

    hatsml: false,
    hatmed: false,
    hatlrg: false,
    hatxlrg: false,
    hatxxlrg: false,

    hatsmlqty: 0,
    hatmedqty: 0,
    hatlrgqty: 0,
    hatxlrgqty: 0,
    hatxxlrgqty: 0,

    hatsmltot: 0,
    hatmedtot: 0,
    hatlrgtot: 0,
    hatxlrgtot: 0,
    hatxxlrgtot: 0,
}
},
watch: {

hoodiesml() {
    let app = this
    if (app.hoodiesml === false) {
        app.hoodiesmlqty = 0
        console.log('hoodiesml qty set to 0')
    }

    else if (app.hoodiesml === true) {
        app.hoodiesmlqty = 1
    }
},

hoodiesmlqty() {
    let app = this
    let tot = 0
    tot = app.hoodiesmlqty * app.hoodieCost
    app.hoodiesmltot = tot
    console.log('some hoodiesmlqty changed ' + tot)
    app.merchtotal()
},


hatsml() {
    let app = this
    if (app.hatsml === false) {
        app.hatsmlqty = 0
        console.log('hatsml qty set to 0')
    }

    else if (app.hatsml === true) {
        app.hatsmlqty = 1
    }
},

hatsmlqty() {
    let app = this
    let tot = 0
    tot = app.hatsmlqty * app.hatCost
    app.hatsmltot = tot
    console.log('some hatsmlqty changed ' + tot)
    app.merchtotal()
},

shirtsml() {
    let app = this
    if (app.shirtsml === false) {
        app.shirtsmlqty = 0
        console.log('shirtsml qty set to 0')
    }

    else if (app.shirtsml === true) {
        app.shirtsmlqty = 1
    }
},

shirtsmlqty() {
    let app = this
    let tot = 0
    tot = app.shirtsmlqty * app.shirtCost
    app.shirtsmltot = tot
    console.log('some shirtsmlqty changed ' + tot)
    app.merchtotal()
},
```

This is only showing the watcher for 2 sizes out of 5 per item. There could be more than 3 items also.

I'm using Django and I thought about just leaving it all in the database side, but I handle payment from this page.

The process is I hand the total off to paypal express directly from this page.

**The process flow:**

The user fills in a form (that adds a cost to the total price). They click checkout, that's where I check for errors. If there are no errors, The checkout button becomes visible, in a modal. Above the checkout button I have event merchandise they can buy in different sizes. I have to have that total ready when they scroll down and click the paypal checkout button. That's why I have the watchers.

**My Question**

Is there a way have a watcher watch multiple properties. i.e have it watch all of the quantities and sizes of the hats and if one changes call a method where I can pass in the quantity and cost. This way I can have just one method and one watcher?

Comment: Maybe you talk about deep watch?

Comment: https://codepen.io/denis_efremov/pen/eEMmoN

Comment: Ill look into this.

Comment: Watcher must receive arguments. shirtsmlqty (newValue, oldValue) {}

Comment: Post your working code to run it as snippet here

Comment: https://codepen.io/unitedideas/pen/xyzaxr

Comment: `v-else="hoodiesml"` did you read Vue docs?

Comment: `this.app = this;` do you understand what that code means?

Comment: Try to read other apps code. You have invalid approach from the start.

Comment: that was supposed to be let app = this

Comment: what's the invalid approach?

Comment: I appreciate the immediate feedback, but "did you read the documents" doesn't really point me in the right direction. I don't need someone to write the code for me I just need direction. I'll do the rest.

Comment: eek should have used an object you know you can do `watch: {'some.nested.object': function(){...}}` right?

Comment: thanks @LawrenceCherone I'll go read up on that. Do you think I should use an object for each item and have key, value for each of the sizes? hat{small:0, med:2, lg:0}?  or are you thinking an object for each of the items (hat, hoodie, shirt)?  My first inclination is key:value for each size and creating an object for each item. -thanks

Comment: Yeah, or go even deeper, `items: {hat{small:0, med:2, lg:0}}` then it gives you alittle more room for state variables, I always treat it like traditional global scope, and think twice about the structure of the data. You can watch as nested as you like, also if you organize it you often wont need watchers. and `app` is not needed, use `this`

Comment: @ShaneCheek you should read docs few times before use vue

Comment: Thanks @piterden I will continue to read the docs. But sometimes you just need to jump in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally,

I would not define/hardcode each item but use a property of the object/item to define a state, so for example, `type` could be anything from hoodies to unicorns, and other value like `size` could be disabled by false etc. Then all you do in the ui is update the model/item.

Also, I would abstract out the items into a component for giggles.

```js
Vue.component('cart-item', {
  template: '#cart-item',
  props: ['data', 'index'],
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        type: this.data.type,
        price: this.data.price,
        size: this.data.size,
        qty: this.data.qty
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateOrder(e) {
      this.$emit('on-update', this.item, this.index)
    }
  }
});

//
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    cartTotal: function() {
      let total = 0
      this.items.forEach(item => {
        total = total + item.qty * item.price
      })
      return total
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
        type: 'T-shirt',
        price: 9.99,
        size: '',
        qty: 0
      }, {
        type: 'Unicorn Plush Toy',
        price: 3.99,
        size: false,
        qty: 0
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateCart(value, index) {
      this.items[index] = Object.assign(this.items[index], value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Order Form</h1>

  <cart-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :data="item" :index="index" @on-update="updateCart"></cart-item>

  <p>Total cart cost: ${{ cartTotal }}</p>

  <pre>{{ items }}</pre>
</div>

<template id="cart-item">
   <div>
     <strong>{{ item.type }}</strong><br>
     <strong>{{ item.price }}</strong><br>
     <div v-if="item.size !== false">
     <label>Size</label>
     <select v-model="item.size" @change="updateOrder">
       <option>sml</option>
       <option>med</option>
       <option>lrg</option>
       <option>xlrg</option>
     </select>
     </div>
     <label>Qty</label>
     <input type="text" v-model="item.qty" @input="updateOrder"/>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I’ll need to get my head wrapped around objects and components.